# Edits to my answers sometimes generate multiple answers rather than applying the edits

Tags: bug, editing, answers

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/295088/avoid-repetition-of-to-be-verb/295092#295092), I answered it, then edited my answer a few times in rapid succession. Each time I used the "edit" link.

Now I notice that there are two separate answers, one being [an earlier draft](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/295092/113306), and the other being [the final edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/295091/113306).

Seems like a bug. It's happened to me twice in the last 24 hours, and never before, that I've noticed.

If possible, I'd like to keep the upvote on the early draft, which should be deleted.

Comment: [This old bug report of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337715/295232) may be related, but I'm not sure if you used the back button or not. And if that's the only way this can happen.

Comment: @Glorfindel That may have been it. It's possible I used the back button without thinking since it's a hot button on my mouse. Odd that hasn't been patched. It's a bug, no doubt.